# How to set all array's elements into one variable in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

For example i've got one array like

```
int[] array = {1,0,0,1,0}
```

and one `int variable=0;`

I want set all array's elements into variable. How can i do this?

```
variable=10010
```

In addition if we think about reverse of this situation? Variable's values set to array?

```
int something=10000 to int[] something={1,0,0,0,0}
```

**Thanks for your all contribution**

Comment: Hi, your array will be always "bits"  ? and your variable will be always a string ?

Comment: Not always bits, it could be any value. Im just trying set the all value of array to variable, array and variable could be int, string etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest quickest method I could think of.

```
        byte[] array = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
        string temp = "";
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            temp += array[i].ToString();

        result = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
```

Comment: It works ! I was trying like that it seems close to yours haha ,  int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int variable;

            for(int i=0; i<= array.Length;i++)
            {
                variable = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
            }

Comment: Glad you found something to fit the need.

Answer (score 2):

```
        //==============go forwards===================
        int[] array = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
        int variable = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
            //first element
            if (i == 0)
                variable = array[i];
            else
            {
                variable *= 10;
                variable += array[i];
            }
        }

        //print resualts 
        Console.WriteLine(variable);




        //===================go backwards===============
        int variable2 = 10010;

        //convert it into a char array
        string value = variable2+"";

        //set the array length based on the size
        int[] reverse = new int[value.Length];

        //loop
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
        {
            //grab the number from a char value and push it into the array
            reverse[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(value[i]);
        }

        //print out
        for(int i = 0; i <reverse.Length;++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "] = " + reverse[i]);
        }
```

Comment: But for a reverse version it is so helpful thanks a lot !

Comment: You don't need that first if/else. If `i` = 0 then `variable` = 0 and doing `variable *= 10;` won't change the value at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this, but not as compact as others.  This approach demonstrates bit-wise operations to construct an int from the array of 0's and 1's.

```
class Program
{     
    // converts array of 0's and 1's to an int, and assumes big endian format.
    static int bitArrayToInt(int[] bit_array)
    {
        int rc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bit_array.Length; i++)
        {
            rc <<= 1; // bit shift left
            rc |= bit_array[i]; // set LSB according to arr[i]. 
        }
        return rc;
    }        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
        int rc = bitArrayToInt(array);

        System.Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} binary",rc, Convert.ToString(rc, 2));
        System.Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
```

There's a huge number of choices on how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone here, so bear with me, but if performance isn't an issue then how about something like:

```
int.Parse(string.Join(string.Empty, array.Select(d => d.ToString()));
```

Obviously you'll need some error handling around the parsing for overflows, invalid characters, etc.